# aldryn-newsblog view permissions

Tags: django-cms, divio

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here, but I've not been able to find the answer.

I have a DjanoCMS website the uses **aldryn-newsblog**. I've created a few pages and articles within those pages. All works great as long as I'm logged in as admin. If I logout, the articles go away.

I want to deploy the application and allow everyone to be able to view (but not edit of course) all the content without having to login. Probably a permissions issue, but I can't find the answer.

All the other pages on the site that do not use aldryn-newsblog work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I knew this was something very basic. I simply did not publish the **articles** in the aldryn-newsblog app. So, I could see them when I was logged in as admin, but not when I logged out. Duh!